# Determine if this series is convergent or not

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I've been going crazy for a long time in determining if this series converges or diverges.
Most likely it converges, but I really don't know which criterion to apply for resolution.
Could you give me support? Thanks a lot to everyone

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n+4)-\ln(n)}{\sqrt{3n+4}}$$

I tried to rationalize and apply the asymptotic comparison criterion in this way

$$a_n=\frac{\ln(n+4)-\ln(n)}{\sqrt{3n+4}} = \frac{\ln(\frac{n+4}{n}) \sqrt{3n+4}}{{3n+4}} ≃ \frac{\sqrt{3n}}{3n} ≃ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

But in this way the series diverges... :(

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Maybe you can use $\log(1+x) \le x$ for $x \ge 1$. And do a little work.

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes from

$$\ln(\frac{n+4}{n})=\ln(1+4/n)\approx 4/n$$

Therefore you have finally an equivalence with a general term $k \frac{1}{n \sqrt{n}}$ giving a  convergent series.

Comment: Thank you too much

Answer (score 1):

I think the same with Jean.

$$\frac{\log \frac{n+4}{n}}{\sqrt{3n+4}}\leq \frac{\frac{4}{n}}{\sqrt{3n+4}} \leq \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} n^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ converges, the series in the problem must be convergent.

Comment: Thank you too much